# Where do I find the source code of GWT?

Tags: gwt

`Please direct me to a place where I can download the source code of GWT`.
I got the main source code link but I got a list of links over there to get the content in read-only format. Is there any way to get the entire source code in zip or any other format.

Answer (score 2):

You can download it.  Here is the link to the instructions.

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/checkout

Answer (score 1):

you can find some information about that here. (lmgtfy removed)

edit: use tortoiseSVN and download it from here: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/checkout

Comment: +1 for the lmgtfy link, which I was going to do, but -1 for using tinyurl.

Comment: stackoverflow is smart about lmgtfy now. it doesn't let you post them.

Comment: @scott you might want to remove your answer to LMGTFY ... we had debates over this link :)

Comment: Sorry for Unclarified question. Actually I got that link but I was unable to download the entire trunk of the sourcecode as the trunk links open a list of links but is there any way to get the entire zip package.

Comment: Thanks :-) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links  Check this link